# Problema de Rstudio con servicio de alojamiento de archivos (Dropbox/OneDrive/GoogleDrive/etc)

Tags: r, rstudio, google-drive

Cree un nuevo proyecto en r, pero cada vez que escribo en el script me sale ese mensaje que esta en imagen, y sí lo guardo y sigo escribiendo vuelve y sale el error.
qué debo de hacer para que no salga mas ese error?
Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es posible que estés trabajando en una carpeta que se  sincroniza con alguna nube como dropbox o onedrieve. ¿Podrías verificar esto?. En tal caso la solución es prevenir la sincronizacion de la carpeta ".Rproj.user" la cual suele estar oculta.

Comment: Si el proyecto lo estoy guardando en drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al crear un proyecto dentro de RStudio, sus archivos de proyecto son monitoreados activamente para detectar cambios. Esto permite a RStudio indexar funciones y archivos para habilitar la finalización del código y la navegación. Si está utilizando 
simultáneamente la aplicación Dropbox/OneDrive/Dropbox para sincronizar de forma remota su trabajo, estas también supervisan activamente sus archivos.

Para evitar conflictos, debe decirles que ignoren el directorio **.Rproj.user**
dentro de su Proyecto RStudio. Por ejemplo:

```
.../Dropbox/RStudioProject/.Rproj.user
```

**Tenga en cuenta que este es un directorio oculto**

Para solucionarlo primero  asegúrese de salir de RStudio.

- Para ignorar un archivo en Dropbox, deberá usar la función de
  sincronización selectiva de Dropbox .  Luego ve a las preferencias de
  Dropbox | Avanzado y seleccione Sincronización selectiva Esto abrirá
  un explorador de archivos en el que puede navegar a su Proyecto de
  estudio de RS, y deseleccionar el directorio **.Rproj.user**. [Más detalles](https://help.dropbox.com/es-la/installs-integrations/sync-uploads/selective-sync-overview)
- Elegir los elementos que se sincronizan con Google Drive. En un
  ordenador, haz clic en Copia de seguridad y sincronización Backup and
  Sync. Haz clic en Más Más y luego Preferencias. A la derecha, haz
  clic en las carpetas que quieras sincronizar. Para añadir una carpeta
  que no esté en la lista, haz clic en Elegir carpeta. Añade la carpeta
  que quieras dejar de sincronizar **.Rproj.user**. Haz clic en Aceptar. [Más detalles](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2374987?hl=es)
- [En OneDrive](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/elegir-qu%C3%A9-carpetas-de-onedrive-se-sincronizar%C3%A1n-con-su-equipo-98b8b011-8b94-419b-aa95-a14ff2415e85)

Comment: Listo asunto resuelto, pero si por algún motivo se llega a borrar la carpeta .Rproj.user no se pierde nada del proyecto guardado?

Comment: Lo desconozco. Lo único que no se guarda en la nube es .Rproj.user pero normalmente es una carpeta oculta y no suelo utilizar su contenido. Todo lo demás (es decir, mis datos, scripts y documentos) se guardan en la nube sin problema. Y bueno de manera local el proyecto sigue completo.